# StreamCorruptedException being caught?

Tags: android, object, serialization, storage

I am having trouble storing an object onto the device storage. At first I was getting a [`NotSerializableException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/NotSerializableException.html) so I made the object Serializable and now in the `try {} catch {}` block it is throwing a [`StreamCorruptedException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/StreamCorruptedException.html) which I think points to the line that says `in = new ObjectInputStream(byteArray);`. As a result the list is not being populated. I could populate the list outside the `try {} catch {}` block but that would defeat the purpose of storing the list's object onto the device. Here is the relevant code:

```
public class MainListFragment extends ListFragment implements Serializable {

    OnListSelectedListener mCallback;
    public transient ObjectStorage mainObjectList = new ObjectStorage(); // creates
                                                                        // the
                                                                        // list
                                                                        // of
                                                                        // objects
    SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    int mCurrentPosition = -1;

    // The container Activity must implement this interface so the frag can
    // deliver messages
    public interface OnListSelectedListener {

        /** Called by ListFragment when a list item is selected */
        public void onItemSelected(int position, String schedulename,
                String[] ampm, boolean[] days, int[] times, boolean vibrate);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        updateStorage();
        ByteArrayInputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayInputStream(mPrefs
                .getString("myobject", "").getBytes());
        ObjectInputStream in;
        try {
            in = new ObjectInputStream(byteArray);
            ObjectStorage updatedStorageList = (ObjectStorage) in.readObject();
            Log.i("mydebug", "Populating list with storage");
            CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(),
                    R.layout.listview_item_row, updatedStorageList);
            // setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), layout,
            // arraylist));
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            setListShown(true);
        } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void updateStorage() {
        getActivity();// used for MODE_PRIVATE

        // store object list into android system
        mPrefs = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = mPrefs.edit();
        ByteArrayOutputStream arrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream out;
        try {
            Log.i("mydebug", "Updating object storage");
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(arrayOutputStream);
            out.writeObject(mainObjectList);
            out.close();
            arrayOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ed.putString("myobject", arrayOutputStream.toString());
        ed.commit();
    }
}
```

As well as the LogCat info:

```
03-02 00:41:07.857: I/mydebug(12435): TEMPMAINFRAG: MainListFragment{41dfe598 id=0x7f070028}
03-02 00:41:07.857: I/mydebug(12435): 1
03-02 00:41:07.857: D/AbsListView(12435): Get MotionRecognitionManager
03-02 00:41:07.877: D/AbsListView(12435): Get MotionRecognitionManager
03-02 00:41:07.877: I/mydebug(12435): Updating object storage
03-02 00:41:07.877: W/System.err(12435): java.io.StreamCorruptedException
03-02 00:41:07.877: W/System.err(12435):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:2106)
03-02 00:41:07.877: W/System.err(12435):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:372)
03-02 00:41:07.877: W/System.err(12435):    at com.example.android.fragments.MainListFragment.onStart(MainListFragment.java:94)
03-02 00:41:07.877: W/System.err(12435):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1332)
03-02 00:41:07.877: W/System.err(12435):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:906)
03-02 00:41:07.877: W/System.err(12435):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
03-02 00:41:07.877: W/System.err(12435):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
03-02 00:41:07.877: W/System.err(12435):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:1815)
03-02 00:41:07.877: W/System.err(12435):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:518)
03-02 00:41:07.877: W/System.err(12435):    at com.example.android.fragments.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:104)
03-02 00:41:07.877: W/System.err(12435):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1178)
03-02 00:41:07.887: W/System.err(12435):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5058)
03-02 00:41:07.887: W/System.err(12435):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2061)
03-02 00:41:07.887: W/System.err(12435):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2113)
03-02 00:41:07.887: W/System.err(12435):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3554)
03-02 00:41:07.887: W/System.err(12435):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
03-02 00:41:07.887: W/System.err(12435):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1230)
03-02 00:41:07.887: W/System.err(12435):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-02 00:41:07.887: W/System.err(12435):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-02 00:41:07.887: W/System.err(12435):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
03-02 00:41:07.887: W/System.err(12435):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 00:41:07.887: W/System.err(12435):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-02 00:41:07.887: W/System.err(12435):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
03-02 00:41:07.887: W/System.err(12435):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
03-02 00:41:07.887: W/System.err(12435):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-02 00:41:07.947: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(12435): <ConfigWindowMatch:2087>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-02 00:41:08.908: I/mydebug(12435): TEMPMAINFRAG: MainListFragment{41e237f8 id=0x7f070028}
03-02 00:41:08.908: I/mydebug(12435): 1
03-02 00:41:08.918: D/AbsListView(12435): Get MotionRecognitionManager
03-02 00:41:08.928: D/AbsListView(12435): Get MotionRecognitionManager
03-02 00:41:08.938: I/mydebug(12435): Updating object storage
03-02 00:41:08.938: W/System.err(12435): java.io.StreamCorruptedException
03-02 00:41:08.938: W/System.err(12435):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:2106)
03-02 00:41:08.938: W/System.err(12435):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:372)
03-02 00:41:08.938: W/System.err(12435):    at com.example.android.fragments.MainListFragment.onStart(MainListFragment.java:94)
03-02 00:41:08.938: W/System.err(12435):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1332)
03-02 00:41:08.938: W/System.err(12435):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:906)
03-02 00:41:08.938: W/System.err(12435):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
03-02 00:41:08.938: W/System.err(12435):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
03-02 00:41:08.948: W/System.err(12435):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:1815)
03-02 00:41:08.948: W/System.err(12435):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:518)
03-02 00:41:08.948: W/System.err(12435):    at com.example.android.fragments.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:104)
03-02 00:41:08.948: W/System.err(12435):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1178)
03-02 00:41:08.948: W/System.err(12435):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5058)
03-02 00:41:08.948: W/System.err(12435):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2061)
03-02 00:41:08.948: W/System.err(12435):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2113)
03-02 00:41:08.948: W/System.err(12435):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3554)
03-02 00:41:08.948: W/System.err(12435):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
03-02 00:41:08.948: W/System.err(12435):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1230)
03-02 00:41:08.948: W/System.err(12435):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-02 00:41:08.948: W/System.err(12435):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-02 00:41:08.958: W/System.err(12435):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
03-02 00:41:08.958: W/System.err(12435):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 00:41:08.958: W/System.err(12435):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-02 00:41:08.958: W/System.err(12435):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
03-02 00:41:08.958: W/System.err(12435):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
03-02 00:41:08.958: W/System.err(12435):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-02 00:41:09.178: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(12435): <ConfigWindowMatch:2087>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-02 00:41:52.326: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12435): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
03-02 00:41:52.326: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12435): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
03-02 00:41:52.326: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12435): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
03-02 00:41:52.326: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12435): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
03-02 00:41:52.326: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12435): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
03-02 00:41:52.326: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12435): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
03-02 00:41:52.336: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12435): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
03-02 00:41:52.336: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12435): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
03-02 00:41:52.336: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12435): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
03-02 00:41:52.336: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12435): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
03-02 00:41:52.336: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12435): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
03-02 00:41:52.336: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12435): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
03-02 00:41:52.336: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12435): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
03-02 00:41:52.336: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12435): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
03-02 00:41:52.336: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12435): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
03-02 00:41:52.336: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12435): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
03-02 00:41:52.336: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12435): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
03-02 00:41:52.336: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12435): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
03-02 00:41:52.336: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12435): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
03-02 00:41:52.336: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12435): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
03-02 00:41:52.336: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12435): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
03-02 00:41:52.336: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(12435): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of all the ByteArrayInput/OutputStreams, conversions to String, String.getBytes() calls, and everything else that isn't a direct call of writeObject() with the object you want to serialise, connected directly to a FileOutputStream, or conversely a direct read of the object you want from an ObjectInputStream connected directly to a FileInputStream.

You are corrupting the data at three or four separate points. There is no actual need for any of this malarkey even if it didn't corrupt the data, which it does.